# Wrapping text, using call function to pass data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to understand a block of d3 code made by mbostock which wraps long text labels.

Full example and code: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7555321

This example has been referenced on SO before, but I am having trouble understanding how the ".tick" class has a text element that can be selected and being passed into the "wrap" function.

```
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis)
.selectAll(".tick text")      //text selected here
  .call(wrap, x.rangeBand());    //wrap function called here

function wrap(text, width) {
  text.each(function() {
    var text = d3.select(this),
        words = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse(),    //text manipulated here
```

I think that when "xAxis()" is called and then the scale(x) is specified the "name" data is being attached, but I cannot understand how this data is being passed and accessed in the "wrap()" function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The axis component creates a specific structure when called. In particular, it creates the `text` elements with class `tick` and binds the data that represents the tick values to them. The `.call()` function used in the code actually passed the entire selection (in this case of the `text` elements`) to the function given as argument. This is`text`argument in the`wrap` function.

The `.each()` call inside `wrap()` then iterates over all those elements. `d3.select(this)` selects each element and `.text()` accesses the text content of the element (there are other, non-D3 ways of accessing this as well). The text content is the actual text that is being shown with the axis tick, which is what is being broken into lines here.